# Google app engine how to get part from url in a get request?

Tags: google-app-engine

my url is: "http://localhost:8080/i/agt0b3R0eXN3b3JsZHIQCxIJSW1hZ2VCbG9iGIUDDA.jpg" and I just want the "agt0b3R0eXN3b3JsZHIQCxIJSW1hZ2VCbG9iGIUDDA" part.

my app.yaml looks like:

```
handlers:
- url: /i/.*
  script: static_images.py
```

statc_images.py:

```
class StaticImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        image_blob_key = db.Key(self.request.get('')) # here I need the blob_key from url, in this case is "agt0b3R0eXN3b3JsZHIQCxIJSW1hZ2VCbG9iGIUDDA"

        image_blob = db.get(image_blob_key)

        if image_blob:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
            self.response.out.write(image_blob.data)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Image not available")

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/i/(\d+)\.jpg', StaticImage)], debug=True) # im not pretty sure this is good: '/i/(\d+)\.jpg'
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: Belongs on http://www.stackoverflow.com...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are pretty close.  Try this:

```
class StaticImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
        image_blob = ImageModel.get(blob_key)
        # if you want to use db.get you could.

        if image_blob:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
            self.response.out.write(image_blob.data)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Image not available")

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/i/(.*)\.jpg', StaticImage)], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You might want to list the differences, for clarity: Parenthesize the relevant part of the URL regular expression, and add a parameter to the get method to accept the value of the subexpression.